# How to use ipython ZMQ-based console by default

Tags: ipython

I often use `ipython` with `vim` (`vim-ipython` plugin). It connects to ipython via ZMQ, so I need to run `ipython console`. I don't see any purpose to not use `ipython console` even if I don't use ZMQ features, so I want `ipython` to start ZMQ-based console without typing `console`. I know, that this problem could be partly solved with bash aliases, but I think that I would have problems with launching `qtconsole` or `notebook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't provide any way to make `ipython console` the default, and we're probably not about to, as it gets much less field testing than the regular terminal IPython. I'd recommend you just alias another convenient name to it.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Where can I read about key differences between `ipython` and `ipython console`? I've tried to google it ("ipython console"), but it's _console_ is a very common word to search for.

Comment: console use ZMQ, so things like `input` wont work, console will not startup if zmq not availlable, things like vi/curses won't work either... etc. Wherease they do on "normal" IPython.

Comment: We don't really have any documentation of it, but most of the code that makes it different is in this file:https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/terminal/console/interactiveshell.py